# MySQL query works in sql developer but does not work in jaspersoft studio 6

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I need to create a report which has 4 parameters: $P{NursingStation},$P{ServiceCentre},$P{ServicePoint},$P{StoreNew}
The above parameters are actually the resources associated with a user login. The objective is that if any of the above parameters ( all 4 or less that 4 ) are entered, the report should give the correct user login.
The sql query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    hu.user_login  AS UserLogin 
FROM
    his_user hu
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, ns.station_name FROM user_resource_map u, nursingstation_master ns WHERE ns.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='NS' AND resource_id=$P{NursingSttion})urm ON (urm.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, sc.description service_center_name FROM user_resource_map u, service_center sc WHERE sc.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='SC' AND resource_id=$P{ServiceCentre})urm1 ON (urm1.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, sp.description service_point_name FROM user_resource_map u, service_point sp WHERE sp.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='SP' AND resource_id=$P{ServicePoint})urm2 ON (urm2.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, sm.description store_name FROM user_resource_map u, store_master sm WHERE sm.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='SM' AND resource_id=$P{StoreNew})urm3 ON (urm3.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
WHERE
    CASE WHEN $P{NursingSttion} = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE station_name IS NOT NULL END
    AND CASE WHEN $P{ServiceCentre} = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE service_center_name IS NOT NULL END 
    AND CASE WHEN $P{ServicePoint} = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE service_point_name IS NOT NULL END
    AND CASE WHEN $P{StoreNew}="" THEN 1=1 ELSE store_name IS NOT NULL END
```

I came up with this query after a discussion with a colleague.It works fine in developer(Sqlyog) with hard coded values. It gives expected output.
When I put the query in as jasper studio and preview it, it says empty document.

I have hard coded the query in jasper studio as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT hu.user_login  AS UserLogin
    
FROM
    his_user hu
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, ns.station_name FROM user_resource_map u, nursingstation_master ns WHERE ns.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='NS' AND resource_id=11)urm ON (urm.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, sc.description service_center_name FROM user_resource_map u, service_center sc WHERE sc.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='SC' AND resource_id=13)urm1 ON (urm1.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, sp.description service_point_name FROM user_resource_map u, service_point sp WHERE sp.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='SP' AND resource_id='')urm2 ON (urm2.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u.his_user_login, sm.description store_name FROM user_resource_map u, store_master sm WHERE sm.id=u.resource_id AND resource_type='SM' AND resource_id=10018)urm3 ON (urm3.his_user_login=hu.user_login)
WHERE
    CASE WHEN 11 = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE station_name IS NOT NULL END
    AND CASE WHEN 13 = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE service_center_name IS NOT NULL END 
    AND CASE WHEN '' = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE service_point_name IS NOT NULL END
    AND CASE WHEN 10018 = "" THEN 1=1 ELSE store_name IS NOT NULL END;
```

It gives the expected output in preview of the jasper. Please help me understand why i am getting blank output or what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `""`  I do not understand.  `''`?

Comment: It is to account for the choice when a parameter is not entered. Meaning only three parameters are entered and the fourth one is not entered.

Comment: Is that a MySQL convention? I only know double quotes only from column/table names.

Comment: That is how i have seen the parameters values hard coding. If there is any other way to check parameters, do share.

Comment: This query works in ireport 1.2.0 and the jasper gives the expected output